# If $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disk and $f(0)=0$, then $\lvert f(z) + f(-z) \rvert \le 2 \lvert z \rvert^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a complex valued function holomorphic on the unit disk with $f(0) = 0$. Then $\lvert f(z) + f(-z) \rvert \le 2 \lvert z \rvert^2$.

I was looking at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1012989/476533) but I still unsure about certain steps.

$\textbf{proof attempt.}$

Define $g(z) = \frac{f(z) + f(-z)}{2}$ (which is also holomorphic). Then $g(0) = 0$ and **if I could show $\lvert g(z) \rvert \le 1$**, then by Schwarz's lemma $\lvert g(z) \rvert \le \lvert z \rvert$. Now define $h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z}$, and by Riemann removable singularity theorem we can define $h(z)$ on all of $D(0,1)$ since $h$ is bounded at $z=0$ since $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{g(z)}{z} = g'(0) = 0$. Thus $h(0) = 0$ and $\lvert h(z) \rvert = \lvert \frac{g(z)}{z} \rvert \le 1$ finally applying Schwarz's lemma to $h$ we obtain $\lvert \frac{g(z)}{z} \rvert \le \lvert z \rvert$ which is the desired result.  //

How do I show $\lvert g(z) \rvert \le 1$?

Comment: Note that in the original question it was given that $f\colon\Bbb D\to\Bbb D$, so $|f(z)+f(-z)|\le |f(z)|+|f(-z)|\le 2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, that's it, thank you. I should have been more careful with those conditions.

Comment: I don't think the statement is true. $f(z)=1+1/(z-1)=z/(z-1)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Why your $f$ should be holomorphic on the unit disk?

Comment: @SergeiGolovan $f(\mathbb D)\subseteq\mathbb D$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke $f(z)=z/(z-1)$ defines $f$ quite holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb D=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}$.

Comment: @Did That wasn't in the original question.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan A pretty obvious omission, mentioned by Ted 6 minutes and acknowledged by the OP 3 minutes before you posted your comment.

Comment: @Did Yeah, I missed the acknowledging comment. Thank you for pointing out